ping pong game glitching out after a certain amount of hits
Im making a ping pong game and it's glitching out after a certain amount of hits, what do i do? So after exactly 25 hits the ball goes to the other side like normal but then it crosses the net in the middle, dissapears, and gives me the point. how do it fix this?
I have a html file and a javascript file, heres the code for both:


var x = document.getElementById("background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3");

function playAudio() {
  x.play();
}

function pauseAudio() {
  x.pause();
}

// select canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("pong");

// getContext of canvas = methods and properties to draw and do a lot of thing to the canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// load sounds
let hit = new Audio();
let wall = new Audio();
let userScore = new Audio();
let comScore = new Audio();
hit.src = "sounds/hit.mp3";
wall.src = "sounds/wall.mp3";
comScore.src = "sounds/comScore.mp3";
userScore.src = "sounds/userScore.mp3";

// Ball object
const ball = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  radius: 10,
  velocityX: 5,
  velocityY: 5,
  speed: 7,
  color: "WHITE"
}

// User Paddle
const user = {
  x: 0, // left side of canvas
  y: (canvas.height - 100) / 2, // -100 the height of paddle
  width: 10,
  height: 100,
  score: 0,
  color: "WHITE"
}

// COM Paddle
const com = {
  x: canvas.width - 10, // - width of paddle
  y: (canvas.height - 100) / 2, // -100 the height of paddle
  width: 10,
  height: 100,
  score: 0,
  color: "WHITE"
}

// NET
const net = {
  x: (canvas.width - 2) / 2,
  y: 0,
  height: 10,
  width: 2,
  color: "WHITE"
}

// draw a rectangle, will be used to draw paddles
function drawRect(x, y, w, h, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

// draw circle, will be used to draw the ball
function drawArc(x, y, r, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

// listening to the mouse
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getMousePos);

function getMousePos(evt) {
  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  user.y = evt.clientY - rect.top - user.height / 2;
}

// when COM or USER scores, we reset the ball
function resetBall() {
  ball.x = canvas.width / 2;
  ball.y = canvas.height / 2;
  ball.velocityX = -ball.velocityX;
  ball.speed = 7;
}

// draw the net
function drawNet() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += 15) {
    drawRect(net.x, net.y + i, net.width, net.height, net.color);
  }
}

// draw text
function drawText(text, x, y) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  ctx.font = "75px fantasy";
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

// collision detection
function collision(b, p) {
  p.top = p.y;
  p.bottom = p.y + p.height;
  p.left = p.x;
  p.right = p.x + p.width;

  b.top = b.y - b.radius;
  b.bottom = b.y + b.radius;
  b.left = b.x - b.radius;
  b.right = b.x + b.radius;

  return p.left < b.right && p.top < b.bottom && p.right > b.left && p.bottom > b.top;

}

// update function, the function that does all calculations

function update() {

  // change the score of players, if the ball goes to the left "ball.x<0" computer win, else if "ball.x > canvas.width" the user win

  if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0) {
    com.score++;
    comScore.play();
    resetBall();

  } else if (ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width) {

    user.score++;
    userScore.play();
    resetBall();

  }


  // the ball has a velocity
  ball.x += ball.velocityX;
  ball.y += ball.velocityY;


  // computer plays for itself, and we must be able to beat it

  // simple AI
  let computerLevel = 1;
  com.y += (ball.y - (com.y + com.height / 2)) * computerLevel;

  // when the ball collides with bottom and top walls we inverse the y velocity.

  if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0 || ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height) {
    ball.velocityY = -ball.velocityY;
    wall.play();
  }

  // we check if the paddle hit the user or the com paddle
  let player = (ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width / 2) ? user : com;

  // if the ball hits a paddle
  if (collision(ball, player)) {

    // play sound
    hit.play();

    // we check where the ball hits the paddle
    let collidePoint = (ball.y - (player.y + player.height / 2));

    // normalize the value of collidePoint, we need to get numbers between -1 and 1.

    // -player.height/2 < collide Point < player.height/2

    collidePoint = collidePoint / (player.height / 2);

    // when the ball hits the top of a paddle we want the ball, to take a -45degees angle

    // when the ball hits the center of the paddle we want the ball to take a 0degrees angle

    // when the ball hits the bottom of the paddle we want the ball to take a 45degrees

    // Math.PI/4 = 45degrees

    let angleRad = (Math.PI / 4) * collidePoint;

    // change the X and Y velocity direction

    let direction = (ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width / 2) ? 1 : -1;

    ball.velocityX = direction * ball.speed * Math.cos(angleRad);

    ball.velocityY = ball.speed * Math.sin(angleRad);

    // speed up the ball everytime a paddle hits it.

    ball.speed += 0.1;

  }

}

// render function, the function that does al the drawing

function render() {

  // clear the canvas
  drawRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "#000");

  // draw the user score to the left
  drawText(user.score, canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 5);

  // draw the COM score to the right
  drawText(com.score, 3 * canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 5);

  // draw the net
  drawNet();

  // draw the user's paddle
  drawRect(user.x, user.y, user.width, user.height, user.color);

  // draw the COM's paddle
  drawRect(com.x, com.y, com.width, com.height, com.color);

  // draw the ball
  drawArc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, ball.color);

}

function game() {
  update();
  render();
}

// number of frames per second
let framePerSecond = 50;

//call the game function 50 times every 1 Sec
let loop = setInterval(game, 1000 / framePerSecond);
body {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#pong {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
<audio id="background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3" loop>
  <source src="background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>

<canvas id="pong" width="600" height="400"></canvas>




You should limit the ball speed by doing ball.speed += 0.1; to ball.speed = Math.min(ball.speed + 0.1, 10); and then adjust the ball position after the hit, because increasing too much after each hit, causing it to cross the net and disappear:
if(ball.velocityX > 0) {
  ball.x = player.x + player.width + ball.radius; // Adjust for right paddle
} else {
  ball.x = player.x - ball.radius; // Adjust for left paddle
}



var x = document.getElementById("background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3"); 

function playAudio() { 
x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
x.pause(); 
} 

// select canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("pong");

// getContext of canvas = methods and properties to draw and do a lot of thing to the canvas
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// load sounds
let hit = new Audio();
let wall = new Audio();
let userScore = new Audio();
let comScore = new Audio();

hit.src = "sounds/hit.mp3";
wall.src = "sounds/wall.mp3";
comScore.src = "sounds/comScore.mp3";
userScore.src = "sounds/userScore.mp3";

// Ball object
const ball = {
    x : canvas.width/2,
    y : canvas.height/2,
    radius : 10,
    velocityX : 5,
    velocityY : 5,
    speed : 7,
    color : "WHITE"
}

// User Paddle
const user = {

    x : 0, // left side of canvas
    y : (canvas.height - 100)/2, // -100 the height of paddle
    width : 10,
    height : 100,
    score : 0,
    color : "WHITE"
}

// COM Paddle
const com = {
    x : canvas.width - 10, // - width of paddle
    y : (canvas.height - 100)/2, // -100 the height of paddle
    width : 10,
    height : 100,
    score : 0,
    color : "WHITE"
}

// NET
const net = {
    x : (canvas.width - 2)/2,
    y : 0,
    height : 10,
    width : 2,
    color : "WHITE"
}

// draw a rectangle, will be used to draw paddles
function drawRect(x, y, w, h, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

// draw circle, will be used to draw the ball
function drawArc(x, y, r, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

// listening to the mouse
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getMousePos);
function getMousePos(evt){
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    user.y = evt.clientY - rect.top - user.height/2;
}

// when COM or USER scores, we reset the ball
function resetBall(){
    ball.x = canvas.width/2;
    ball.y = canvas.height/2;
    ball.velocityX = -ball.velocityX;
    ball.speed = 7;
}

// draw the net
function drawNet(){
    for(let i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i+=15){
        drawRect(net.x, net.y + i, net.width, net.height, net.color);
    }
}

// draw text
function drawText(text,x,y){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.font = "75px fantasy";
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

// collision detection
function collision(b,p){
    p.top = p.y;
    p.bottom = p.y + p.height;
    p.left = p.x;
    p.right = p.x + p.width;
    b.top = b.y - b.radius;
    b.bottom = b.y + b.radius;
    b.left = b.x - b.radius;
    b.right = b.x + b.radius;
    return p.left < b.right && p.top < b.bottom && p.right > b.left && p.bottom > b.top;
}

// update function, the function that does all calculations
function update(){
    // change the score of players, if the ball goes to the left "ball.x<0" computer win, else if "ball.x > canvas.width" the user win
    if( ball.x - ball.radius < 0 ){
        com.score++;
        comScore.play();
        resetBall();
    }else if( ball.x + ball.radius > canvas.width){
        user.score++;
        userScore.play();
        resetBall();
    }

    // the ball has a velocity
    ball.x += ball.velocityX;
    ball.y += ball.velocityY;

    // computer plays for itself, and we must be able to beat it
    // simple AI
    let computerLevel = 1;
    com.y += (ball.y - (com.y + com.height/2)) * computerLevel;

    // when the ball collides with bottom and top walls we inverse the y velocity.
    if(ball.y - ball.radius < 0 || ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height){
        ball.velocityY = -ball.velocityY;
        wall.play();
    }

    // we check if the paddle hit the user or the com paddle
    let player = (ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width/2) ? user : com;

    // if the ball hits a paddle

    if(collision(ball,player)){

        // play sound
        hit.play();

        // we check where the ball hits the paddle
        let collidePoint = (ball.y - (player.y + player.height/2));

        // normalize the value of collidePoint, we need to get numbers between -1 and 1.
        // -player.height/2 < collide Point < player.height/2
        collidePoint = collidePoint / (player.height/2);

        // when the ball hits the top of a paddle we want the ball, to take a -45degees angle
        // when the ball hits the center of the paddle we want the ball to take a 0degrees angle
        // when the ball hits the bottom of the paddle we want the ball to take a 45degrees
        // Math.PI/4 = 45degrees
        let angleRad = (Math.PI/4) * collidePoint;

        // change the X and Y velocity direction
        let direction = (ball.x + ball.radius < canvas.width/2) ? 1 : -1;
        ball.velocityX = direction * ball.speed * Math.cos(angleRad);
        ball.velocityY = ball.speed * Math.sin(angleRad);

        if(ball.velocityX > 0) {
            ball.x = player.x + player.width + ball.radius; // Adjust for right paddle
        } else {
            ball.x = player.x - ball.radius; // Adjust for left paddle
        }
        
        // speed up the ball everytime a paddle hits it.
        // ball.speed += 0.1;
        ball.speed = Math.min(ball.speed + 0.1, 10);
    }

}

// render function, the function that does al the drawing
function render(){
    // clear the canvas
    drawRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "#000");

    // draw the user score to the left
    drawText(user.score,canvas.width/4,canvas.height/5);

    // draw the COM score to the right
    drawText(com.score,3*canvas.width/4,canvas.height/5);

    // draw the net
    drawNet();

    // draw the user's paddle
    drawRect(user.x, user.y, user.width, user.height, user.color);

    // draw the COM's paddle
    drawRect(com.x, com.y, com.width, com.height, com.color);

    // draw the ball
    drawArc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, ball.color);
}

function game(){
    update();
    render();
}

// number of frames per second
let framePerSecond = 50;

//call the game function 50 times every 1 Sec
let loop = setInterval(game,1000/framePerSecond); 
body{
    background-color: dimgray;
}
#pong{
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    margin :auto;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
<audio id="background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3" loop>
    <source src="background-music-for-video-short-blog-era-of-cyborgs-54-second-199951.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 
<canvas id="pong" width="600" height="400"></canvas>




Thank you, you fixed the problem. But now since the speed is limited you can never beat the computer, the speed increase was for the ball to increase and eventually be faster than the computer. And since the speed is limited the computer will always be able to hit it back, so the player will always lose. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Also I edited a part of the code: // simple AI let computerLevel = 0.1; com.y += (ball.y - (com.y + com.height / 2)) * computerLevel;   @KeyboardCorporation
